# ReactJs reset interval timer in repeat

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a compontent for `login` and there is you can enter your phone number then get you otp code, you can correct your phone number and also after 30 seconds resend the code. everything almost working fine, except when you click on correct button, the timer going to fast interval, you can press correct button for two or three times, you see time running so fast. I got this issue on resend button, but I solved via:

`this.state.resendTimer = this.timerInterval();`

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz952t0m/)**

To see the issue, 1. enter a fake phone number, 2. click on correct, 3. enter a fake number again, click the button. repeat these for two or three time, you see timer running so fast! but what I want to reset timer to 30 and out normally per second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clear your interval before start again.

Check this out...

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  ...
        
  this.tm = 0;
}



timerInterval = () => {
  this.tm = setInterval(() => {
  ...
  }, 1000);
}
```

and clear interval:

```
clearInterval(this.tm);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84jyag6p/)

Comment: I think instead of assigning "undefined" we should assign 0 to this.tm. As it's time interval and it should not be undefined.

Comment: @Mohit why not assign `null`?

Comment: @Vencovsky It's not a good practice to assign null to a primitive in JS.

Comment: @Mohit could you please explain better?

Comment: I just meant to say that passing a value to clearInterval should be a var i.e. a reference returned by setInterval that ideally should be number but not null. But it's on the choice what to use :)